# TypeScript: chart.js work with regular js but not with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js

I am trying to use typescript with chart.js library.
this is my index file
Index.js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="chart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

with this regular js file, it is working good.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'data',
            borderColor: 'rgb(70,135,255)',
            data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
        }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {}
});
```

But I need to work with typescript so I try to use this code:

```
import { Chart} from 'chart.js';

const canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById("myChart");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'data',
            borderColor: 'rgb(70,135,255)',
            data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
        }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {}
});
```

The typescript generates this file:

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var chart_js_1 = require("chart.js");
var canvas = document.getElementById("myChart");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var chart = new chart_js_1.Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',
    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        datasets: [{
                label: 'data',
                borderColor: 'rgb(70,135,255)',
                data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
            }]
    },
    // Configuration options go here
    options: {}
});
```

while I used the typescript code it doesn't work, thanks for your help!

Comment: How doesn't it work?  Is there an error?

Comment: Not an error but I don't see the graph, I get a blank page instead.

Comment: Is there anything in the console?

Comment: check.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at check.js:2

this is line 2: exports.__esModule = true;

Comment: Ah, looks like an issue with typescript/your environment, not Chart.js